# Maven settings via SSO?

Tags: maven, single-sign-on, nexus

I've got some developers who are unhappy about storing their LDAP username/passwords in settings.xml in order to access Nexus.  Their unhappiness is partly FUD, but also the inconvenience of having to re-encrypt the password whenever their LDAP password expires (which is relatively frequent here).

Is there any way at all to get Maven to use SSO / LDAP instead?  The artifact repository we're using is Nexus, and the web front-end of that does use SSO already.

Comment: User token as Mark mentions does not survive username/password changes like mentioned by RCross. However there is support for the user token to be automatically inserted into the settings.xml that can be downloaded from Nexus. So your password change process would 1. change SSO password, 2. reset user token in Nexus 3. get new settings.xml by calling the settings download goal of the nexus maven plugin. We are still looking at improving that more but ultimately a strict security process is work to deal with.

Comment: The main advantage with user token is that the ldap username and password can not be deciphered from the token at all so the security concern of a password on the disc now concerns Nexus only and not the whole SSO system.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable encryption in the settings.xml file so that it's not sitting there in plain text as well.

http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html#How_to_encrypt_server_passwords

Answer (score 1):

In this case one needs to use [user tokens](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/nexus-repository-administration/user-authentication/security-setup-with-user-tokens). By default this feature is available only in PRO version of Nexus (see [comparison](https://www.sonatype.com/products/repository-oss-vs-pro-features)), but you can use "[Single sign-on patch for Nexus OSS](https://github.com/a-langer/nexus-sso)" which provides an alternative implementation of tokens without violating the license:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/a-langer/nexus-sso.git
cd ./nexus-sso
docker compose up -d
```

Each user can set a personal token that can be used instead of a password. The creation of tokens is implemented through the "NuGet API Key" menu, however, the tokens themselves apply to all types of repositories without exception. Example of usage user token:

1. Go to menu "Nexus -> Manage your user account -> NuGet API Key", press "Access API key".
2. Type your password or username if using SSO login, press "Authenticate".
3. Copy "Your NuGet API Key", press "Close" and "Sign out".
4. The received token can be used instead of a password in settings Docker, Maven and etc.

Answer (score 0):

The latest revision of Nexus has enabled a new security token feature to address this concern. I haven't used it yet, but it's documented here:

- https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/nexus-repository-administration/user-authentication/user-tokens

Comment: The link is broken