# maven deploy to nexus through SSO

Tags: apache, maven, single-sign-on, nexus

I have nexus installed behind of apache server. apache is configured to use SSO, it's triggered in the apache level and then I pass uid through headers.
the problem is that does not work when I want to deploy to nexus with maven.

Have you any idea please

Regards

Comment: Please see [ask] and edit your question: "It does not work" doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: does not work means that we can not use SSO with maven deploy command, I'm sorry but I can't say it any other way.

Comment: SSO is a marketing buzzworld. Unless you document how stuff actually works no one will help you.

Comment: when I access the url, there is a window that appears and I have to validate the request simply with the ok button.
on the other hand this method will not work when I use the maven technical accounts to deploy artifacts on nexus through mvn deploy for example, it is necessary to validate the SSO authentication in graphical mode, normally it is necessary to have a white list or something like that, but really I don't have a clear idea.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want to achieve. Deployments to Nexus should be done by the build server (CI server). You usually use a technical user for this.

Comment: In order to deploy to nexus I have to put the credentials and the repository Url in settings.xml files.

Comment: The credentials should be put into the credentials store of Jenkins and as @JFabianMeier already mentioned done by Jenkins and by a user...never..Furthermore I never understand why people install Nexus behind a supplemental things like Apache, NGINX etc. ? Just use it directly...

Comment: It's not that easy, it's the company strategy

Comment: This duplicate question, see answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12958935/maven-settings-via-sso.